# how can i find all the methods that are called by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

For example:

```
public class Demo{
    public String getReflectString() {
        return "string from reflect";
    }

    public String reflectMethod() throws Exception {
        Method method = ReflectCase.class.getMethod("getReflectString");
        return (String) method.invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Method `Demo#getReflectString` called by reflection，and I wanna find a way to get all the methods in the program that are called this way.

I came up with a solution that has not yet been implemented.

Read the contents of the class file, start from the instruction, find the `Method#invoke`
instruction, and then look back to find the instance that calls the method, and then get the instance corresponding Class and MethodName.

However, this method has a problem, if Class or MethodName or even Method are passed as a parameter, it is difficult to find the corresponding content.

On this basis, think of ways to improve, traverse all the methods, check the instructions of the method. If got `Method#invoke` instruction in method `A()`, and Class and MethodName are passed in as parameters, record method `A()` and the order of parameters. In the following check, if there is a method call `A()`, you can get the value passed to method `A()` Parameters, to obtain the required value.

However, this solution requires traversing the entire program's instructions, which can be very time-consuming when the program is very large. If method call too many levels, the implementation of the algorithm can be quite complicated. So would like to ask, the feasibility of this idea, or is there any better way to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get what you are aminig at. If you want to find all methods, then you need to traverse all methods. However if you are looking for a specific method you could make an interface and then look only at those classes which implement the interface. Please be more specific or give an example.

Comment: @ToBe_HH please check update.